# How to disable the check box in listview c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, checkbox

In windows forms I have a listview with checkbox(listview1.CheckBoxes = true). I want to disable it from the begin and once double click the selected row,then loading a button in a separate tab. once clicked that button need to automatically check the listview checkbox.
How can I do it?

I used this for disable the check box.

```
  private void listview1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
            e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
    }
```

Comment: You can't disable it like you can a `CheckBox` control. You would just have to prevent it being checked programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void listview1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
//way 1
        if (disable)
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
//way 2
        if (disable)
             listview1.Items[0].Checked = false;
    }
```

You can try it, not sure if it meets your needs